# Is it possible to categorize the bash autocomplete output?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, formatting

I have read the [bash programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) on the GNU website, and many good Q&A on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Fortunately, I have made an autocompletion script that works almost exactly as I want. However, there is a final touch I need with formatting the suggestions.

Is there a way to categorize the suggestions based on their types. For instance, I want something like this:

```sh
$ foo --bar # press TAB twice and get the result as below:
* Directories:
foo/   bar/   baz/
* Files:
foo.sh   bar.sh   baz.sh
* Options:
--foo=   --bar   --baz
```

instead of this:

```sh
$ foo --bar # press TAB twice and get the result as below:
--bar      --baz      --foo=      bar/      baz/
foo/       bar.sh     baz.sh      foo.sh
```

A minimal code snippet for the completion script would be:

```sh
_foo(){

   COMPREPLY=()
   local word="$2"
   local prev="$3"

   # Suggest directories
   COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -d -- $word ) )
   
   # Suggest '*.sh' files with negating the '-X' filter pattern
   COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -f -X "![.][sS][hH]$" -- $word ) )

   # Suggest options in the '-W' word list
   COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -W "--foo= --bar --baz" -- $word ) )
}

complete -F _foo foo
```

I appreciate your time, thoughts, and insights :)

## Update:

I tweaked @Socowi 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484931/6474744) so that the extra `\` won't show up before the `=` signs.

```
compgenSection() {
  title="* $1:"
  shift
  local entries
  mapfile -t entries < <(compgen "$@")
  (( "${#entries[@]}" == 0 )) && return
  COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS+=("${entries[@]}")
  mapfile -tO "${#COMPREPLY[@]}" COMPREPLY < <(
    printf "%$((-COLUMNS/2))s\\n" "$title"
    printf %s\\n "${entries[@]}" | sort | column -s $'\n' | expand
  )
  [[ "${COMPREPLY[@]}" =~ "=" ]] && compopt -o nospace
}   
_foo(){
  local word="$2"
  COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS=()
  compgenSection Directories -d -S / -- "$word"
  compgenSection Files -f -X '!*.[sS][hH]' -- "$word"
  compgenSection Options -W '--foo= --bar --baz' -- "$word"
  (( "${#COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS[@]}" <= 1 )) &&
  COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS[@]}")
}
complete -o nosort -F _foo foo
```

Comment: The `nosort` option might help with printing the suggestions just by the order they were introduced. But is there a way to print messages between suggestions? I am already using `printf` to provide user with relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say for sure whether customizing the format is impossible, but if it is, here is a possible workaround just in case:

Add the section titles to `COMPREPLY` to show them at all. Now we have other problems to work around:

1. *The completions are sorted. The section titles appear at the wrong location.*
   **Workaround:** Use `complete -o nosort ...` to show the section titles and entries in the right order. You can manually sort the entries in each section again.
2. *Since bash displays completions in multiple columns the section titles might appear in the same line as other entries.*
   **Workaround:** Force each completion entry to be shown in its own line. Bash formats the entries in `COMPREPLY` into evenly sized columns. If one of the columns is wider than half of the terminal, then all entries will be displayed in their own line. Simply pad the section titles with spaces.
3. *Now all completions are shown in single lines too, but we want them in columns.*
   **Workaround:** Manually put all completions in columns. Then add each line (with possibly multiple entries) as a single entry in `COMPGEN`.
4. *Pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> once to autocomplete doesn't work. Because of the section titles there is always more than one possibility.*
   **Workaround:** make sure to adapt `COMPREPLY` accordingly when `word=$2` changes. If there is only one match in all sections, then the section headers must be suppressed such that `COMPREPLY` contains only that single match. Here we also suppress empty sections to make it look a bit nicer.

## Implementation

```
compgenSection() {
  title="* $1:"
  shift
  local entries
  mapfile -t entries < <(compgen "$@")
  (( "${#entries[@]}" == 0 )) && return
  COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS+=("${entries[@]}")
  mapfile -tO "${#COMPREPLY[@]}" COMPREPLY < <(
    printf "%$((-COLUMNS/2))s\\n" "$title"
    printf %s\\n "${entries[@]}" | sort | column -s $'\n' | expand
  )
}   
_foo(){
  local word="$2"
  COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS=()
  compgenSection Directories -d -- "$word"
  compgenSection Files -f -X '!*.[sS][hH]' -- "$word"
  compgenSection Options -W '--foo= --bar --baz' -- "$word"
  (( "${#COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS[@]}" <= 1 )) &&
  COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY_SECTIONLESS[@]}")
}
complete -o nosort -o filenames -F _foo foo
```

Note that I had to change your `compgen -f -X "![.][sS][hH]$"` since the patterns accepted by `compgen` are globs and not regexes.

I also fixed a problem with `array=( $(compgen ...) )` where filenames with spaces were splited into multiple completion entries. This still happens for filenames with linesbreaks in them. However, this seems like normal behavior: try `touch $'b\na'; cat b`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, which prints `a   b` instead of something like `$'b\na'`.

I also add the option `complete -o filenames` such that entries with spaces in them are correctly quoted upon auto-completion. If this interferes with the completion for options (where you might want actual spaces) you can run the file and directory entries manually trough `printf %q` to still get correct quoting.

## Testing

Here are some examples from an interactive session.
`⌨️`  is the prompt. `↹` marks where I pressed <kbd>tab</kbd>.

```
⌨️ mkdir /tmp/test/{,foo,bar,baz}; cd /tmp/test; touch foo.sh bar.sh baz.sh
⌨️ foo ↹↹
* Directories:                          
bar     baz     foo
* Files:                                
bar.sh  baz.sh  foo.sh
* Options:                              
--bar   --baz   --foo=
⌨️ foo f↹↹
* Directories:                          
foo
* Files:                                
foo.sh
⌨️ foo foo.↹ # auto-completes to `foo foo.sh`
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out ASAP and let you know (and accept the answer) if it works :)

Comment: @Pedram Did it work for you? If not, I would be happy to hear why not.

Comment: Hi @Socowi thanks for checking! I got caught up in other parts of the project and couldn't manage to find the time to implement your suggestion. But, I will work on it and share the results gladly :)

Comment: Thank you @Socowi . I learned some cool tricks from your script :) It looks like you can use `$(tput cols)` to populate the `COLUMNS`  constant. I have encountered one problem so far. A long option that contains a `=` sign prints fine in the suggestions, but it will autocomplete with an extra `\ ` before `=`, i.e. `⌨️ foo --f↹` results in `⌨️ foo --foo\= `

Comment: Oh my bad, `COLUMNS` already contains the number of characters available in the column.

Comment: `complete -o nospace ...` should remove that space. If you still want trailing spaces for *some* entries add those trailing spaces manually to `COMPREPLY`.

Comment: Oh, yes I can get rid of the space and turn it back on using `compopt +o nospace`. But the main problem is with the extra backslash before the equal sign. How can I have `⌨️ foo --foo=` instead of `⌨️ foo --foo\=`?

Comment: I think the backslash comes from `-o filenames`. It might not look nice, but it should be ok since `bash` interprets `foo --foo\=` and `foo --foo=` the same. Your script won't even see a difference once the command is executed.